# Celery - Get all the fail tasks from a particular queue

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

On my application layer,  I've a single worker containing 8 queues, each queue contain task from different category. Each celery task saves record in a distributed DB on servers categorized by different categories.

For eg:- Task for Category A will be queued up in Queue A and will be then forwarded and inserted to Server A and so on.

If any server is down, the celery task will result in failure. And when it gets up again, the child server will ping the application layer that its up and ready to receive the data. I then want to re-run all the failed task for that particular server(category) from which resulted in failure because of some mishappening. **How can I view and re-run the failed task from a particular queue?**

I'd look on Celery Flower API, but it does not gives me an option to get all the fail task from a particular queue. It rather gives a failed task from a particular worker. How can I do it?

Also, Please dont suggest the option for retrying the task using `default_retry_delay=5 * 60, max_retries=12` .